# How to pass data from RootDialog to LuisDialog in Bot Framework

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to pass the user name that i have in Rootdialog to my LuisDialog. but all the intents in LuisDialog accepts only two arguments `(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)`and i don't know how to retrieve the data that i have passed from `LuisResult result. The code to forward to a luis dialog is this :

```
await context.Forward(new Luis(), Resume, UserName, CancellationToken.None);
```

How can i do this please ? which intent will recieve the data ? how can i retrive data from LuisResult object ?

Comment: It's unclear: you want to pass data from your RootDialog to your LuisDialog, or you want to get data from your LuisResult?

Comment: I want to pass data from my RootDialog to my LuisDialog and retrieve this data in my LuisDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to pass the user name that i have in Rootdialog to my LuisDialog.

You can try to define a constructor in your LuisDialog class to accept string type parameter for passing the username from Rootdialog to LuisDialog. The following code snippet works for me, you can refer to it.

***In LuisDialog:***

```
[Serializable]
public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{

    private string uname = "";

    public BasicLuisDialog(string UserName) : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        "{your_modelID_here}",
        "{your_subscriptionKey_here}", 
        domain: "{domain_here}")))
    {
        uname = UserName;
    }

    //....

    // Go to https://luis.ai and create a new intent, then train/publish your luis app.
    // Finally replace "Gretting" with the name of your newly created intent in the following handler
    [LuisIntent("Greeting")]
    public async Task GreetingIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    //....
    //for other intents
    //.... 

    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result) 
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. UserName is : {uname}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}
```

***In RootDialog:***

```
var UserName = "Fei Han";
await context.Forward(new BasicLuisDialog(UserName), AfterLuis, activity, CancellationToken.None);
```

***Test result:***

[image]